# Extending an independent set of vectors to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I would like to check that my argument is correct:
Claim: Given $\{e_i\}$ a set of linearly independent vectors in a vector space $V$. There exists a basis for $V$ that contains $\{e_i\}$.

Let $S$ be the set of all linearly independent subsets of $V$, and order $S$ by inclusion. If $\{e_i\}$ is maximal we are done (there is a small argument here that I'm fine with it).  If it is not maximal, we construct a chain $T$ of $S$ by adding vectors to $\{e_i\}$: $t_1=\{e_i\}$,  $t_2=\{e_i\}\cup \{v_2\}$ where $v_2$ is not in the spam of $\{e_i\}$, and inductively $t_n=t_{n-1}\cup \{v_n\}$. Then the chain $T$ has an upper bound (the union of the elements in the chain) and this upper bound is maximal by the way we constructed the chain , and hence a basis. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set of all linearly independent subsets of V containing $\{e_{i}\}$ ordered by inclusion; then every chain has an upper bound, i.e. the union of elements of the chain.

Then by Zorn Lemma there exists a maximal element, which is a basis for V containing $\{e_{i}\}$.

Instead I'm not sure about your argument, you have to ensure that we can do all the infinite operations.

Comment: I think I don't use Zorn's lemma but instead I use the axiom of choice (to construct the chain $T$) so I guess both proofs rely on the same principle (since you can get Zorn's lemma assuming the axiom of choice).